# Find next in rich edit contrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cricheditctrl

The following code finds the fist occurrence of a word just fine:

```
int len = m_find.LineLength(m_find.LineIndex(0));
CString path;
LPTSTR p = path.GetBuffer(len);
m_find.GetLine(0, p, len);
path.ReleaseBuffer();

// Set the selection to be the first occurrence of the  
// string lpszmyString, if it is found.   
FINDTEXTEX ft;
ft.chrg.cpMin = nEndChar;
ft.chrg.cpMax = -1;
ft.lpstrText = p;
long n = ctrl.FindText(FR_MATCHCASE|FR_WHOLEWORD|FR_DOWN, &ft);
if (n != -1)
{
    ctrl.SetSel(ft.chrgText);
}
```

How do I find the next occurrence?

Answer (score -2):

Set the chrg.cpMin member to be chrgText.cpMax, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787909.aspx

Comment: a) doesn't work, b) links to a different Windows message, c) not supported by either documentation